# Web app: using two hashing schemes for CPU-friendly password validation & secure storage

Tags: passwords, web-application, hash

Consider a web application that:

- uses HTTP Basic Auth over HTTPS, and therefore needs to validate a password (an API Key) on every request
- and needs to handle a substantial load
- has very few distinct users
- the user is given a password and cannot change it (besides requesting a new one), so we can provide randomly generated password

Now, following best practices suggests using a slow hashing algorithm designed for passwords for password storage, e.g. `scrypt`/`bcrypt`/`Argon2`/etc. These are by definition CPU (and/or memory) intensive, which means many more $s are spent on password validation than application logic.

I observe that the passwords are likely to be permanently stored in clear text in memory anyway, because they are being sent in clear text (base64-encoded) as part of every request*. Thus, protecting against application memory attacks appears futile.

Now, to speed up validation, I was considering:

- Storing passwords on disk/in DB using a password hashing algorithm (`scrypt`/`bcrypt`/`Argon2` etc)
- When a password is received by the webapp, and successfully validated, we have effectively "decrypted"/reversed the hashed password. Now this could be stored **in memory** using e.g. salted SHA256 for future validation, which would be much less CPU intensive.

Can anyone spot any issues with the analysis or approach?

* Yes, there's a slight possibility that the web application framework does something really clever to dispose of secrets very shortly after validating them. This is using Spring Boot (Java) - I somehow doubt this is the case.

Comment: Are the passwords always random with at least 128 bits of entropy and they can't be changed by users? If so, you really only need a single iteration, see [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/169320/151903).

Comment: I second this, a key derivation function is a way to increase usability for memorable passwords at the sacrifice of computing effort. A 128 bit key generated with a _cryptographically secure_ random number generator is not crackable through even a single unsalted strong hash.

Comment: Yes, we are in control of the user passwords and can generate them from a cryptographically secure random number generator - I clarified this in the question